# Doubly Linked List of Structures - Overwriting

Tags: c++, pointers, doubly-linked-list

So I am attempting to make a program in C++ that performs basic operations on a doubly linked list. The main problem I am having is that every time I add a new element to the list, the id field I enter for the new element overwrites the id fields of all other elements. The id field is the only field that does this, which is extremely confusing to me. I believe my error could lie somewhere in my use of pointers, as this is my first program in C++ using them to manage a list(Pointers in Ada seem much simpler to me). I have ran my program through GDB step-by-step multiple times and still can't seem to determine what is causing the problem. This leads me to believe that it could be a logic error on my part.

Here is my main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "list.h"
#include <string.h>  // <string>

using namespace std;



int main (void)
{
int choice, printorder;
char idbuffer[100];
rec r; 


do
{  
   cout << "Enter your choice: 1 - Add, 2 - Delete, 3 - Print, 0 - quit. " <<endl;
   cin >> choice;

   switch ( choice )
   {
      case 1:  //AddItem
         cout << "\nEnter ID ";
         cin >> idbuffer;
         r.id = idbuffer;
         cout << "\nFirst Name ";
         cin >> r.firstname;
         cout << "\nLast Name ";
         cin >>  r.lastname;
         if ( AddItem ( r ) )
         {
            cout << "\nSuccess!\n";
         }
         else
         {
            cout << "\nItem failed to be added.\n";
         }
         break;
      case 2:  //Delete
         cout << "\nEnter id: ";
         cin >> idbuffer;
         if ( DeleteItem ( idbuffer ) ) 
         {
            cout << "\nDelete OK.\n";
         }
         else
         {
            cout << "\nDelete Failed for: " << idbuffer << endl;
         }
         break;
      case 3: // Print
        cout << "Enter order: 0 - Ascending, 1 - Descending. \n";
        cin >> printorder;
        PrintList (printorder); 
        break;
      case 0:  // quit
         break;
      default: // bad choice
         break; 
   } // end switch
} 
while ( choice != 0 );// end do while
}  // end main
```

Here is my file list.h:

```
struct rec
{
   char * id;
   char firstname[15];
   char lastname[15];
   rec* prev;
   rec* next;
};


int AddItem ( rec r );
int DeleteItem ( char* delid );
void PrintList ( int order );
```

And finally the AddItem function from my file list.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "list.h"
#include <string.h>

using namespace std; 

rec * first = NULL;
rec * last = NULL;




int AddItem( rec r )
//Return: 1 if a success, 0 if failed.
//No duplicate id's, sort by lastname
{
   rec * ptr = NULL;
   rec * current;

   rec * myStruct = new rec;
   myStruct -> id = r.id;
   strcpy(myStruct -> firstname, r.firstname);
   strcpy(myStruct -> lastname, r.lastname);

   ptr = first;

   //Check for duplicate id's, currently commented out due to id's being overwritten
   //while (ptr)
   //{
   //   if (ptr -> id == myStruct -> id)
   //   {
   //       return 0;
   //   }
   //   ptr = ptr -> next;
   //}

   //ptr = first;

   if (first == NULL) //Empty
   {
      first = myStruct;  //Inserts node into empty list
      last = myStruct;
      myStruct -> prev = NULL;
      myStruct -> next = NULL;
      return 1;
   }
   else if (myStruct -> lastname > last -> lastname) //Add to end of list
   {
      last -> next = myStruct;
      myStruct -> prev = last;
      last = myStruct;
      return 1;
   }
   else if (myStruct -> lastname && myStruct -> lastname < first -> lastname) //Add to beginning of list
   {
      ptr = first;
      first = myStruct;
      myStruct -> next = ptr;
      ptr -> prev = myStruct;
      return 1;
   }
   else
   {
      current = first;
      while (current)
      {
         if (myStruct -> lastname > current -> lastname && myStruct -> lastname <= current -> next -> lastname)
         {
            ptr = current -> next;
            current -> next = myStruct;
            myStruct -> prev = current;
            myStruct -> next = ptr;
            ptr -> prev = myStruct;
            return 1;
         }
         else
         {
            current = current -> next;
         }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I'm sure there are other errors throughout this code and some sloppy programming, but I plan on fixing those up and making the program neater/more efficient after I work out this overwriting problem, as it is also holding me back from testing other parts of my program. Thanks in advance and sorry for the lengthy post.

**Update1:** After realizing I needed to change the line

```
myStruct -> id = r.id;
```

to a string copy, such as:

```
strcpy(myStruct -> id, r.id);
```

I am now receiving a segmentation fault.. I would imagine something with my pointers is messed up. Back to work I go and thanks for all the help so far!

**Update2:** After much more editing and quite a few more errors, I have the program working! I am now in the process of cleaning things up and optimizing the program. Thanks to everyone for the great advice!

Comment: It is C++, so use OOP. Coding C-style in C++ is just bad.

Comment: I am not familiar with OOP, but I'm in a class where we are transitioning from C to C++ and we are currently using a combination of the two. All we've covered from C++ so far are objects, but that was after this assignment was given so we were asked not to use them.

Comment: "*but I'm in a class where we are transitioning from C to C++*" -- Honestly, I see no transition.  It's basically still `C` you're writing.

Comment: Bad idea. C and C++ are different languages. And a basic list would be a good introduction to OOP.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie We've just began transitioning in class, in lab we haven't done anything yet(to my knowledge) that is strictly C++. But we do use a C++ compiler for all of our programs so I assumed this could fall under C/C++. Sorry for the mistake, should I edit my question so it only says C?

Comment: @Olaf oh are they really bad to mix the two? I always thought of C++ as an advancement of C, similar to Ada coming out with new versions that still work with the previous ones. Sorry if that is common knowledge, it appears I have a lot to learn.

Comment: If you really were transitioning from C to C++, you would, at the very least, start using `std::string`, and not `char*`, `strcpy`, etc.

Comment: @Lareaper: Whoever told you that C++ is "C with classes" or an "advancement" does not know at least on of the languages to teach it/them. They have different features and different semantics for identical(!) syntax. C++ is **not** a new version of C! As you bring in Ada: It is more like comparing Ada and Pascal or Modula. (Just to add we're talking about standard C (C11) and C++ (C++14), not some historical versions where C++ was a C preprocessor).

Comment: @Olaf: Oh wow. Thanks for the heads up! I'll be sure to keep that in mind in the future, and after I'm done with this class I'll be sure to get into the habit of not mixing the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All id objects have the same value - the address of the first character of `idbuffer`.

In main

```
cin >> idbuffer;
r.id = idbuffer;
       ^^^^^^^^^
```

and then further in `AddItem`

```
int AddItem( rec r )
//Return: 1 if a success, 0 if failed.
//No duplicate id's, sort by lastname
{
   rec * ptr = NULL;
   rec * current;

   rec * myStruct = new rec;
   myStruct -> id = r.id;
                    ^^^^^
   //...
```

You should dynamically allocate memory that will be pointed to by `id` and there the actual string with id will be copied. Or you should declare data member `id` as a character array.

For example in `main`

```
cin >> idbuffer;
r.id = new char[std::strlen( idbuffer ) + 1];
std::strcpy( r.id, idbuffer );
```

and in `AddItem`

```
rec * myStruct = new rec( r );
```

A better approach is to use an object of type `std::string`.

Comment: So the error lies in the main then? Our professor provided us with the main file, and I am, to my knowledge, the only person in the class who has had this problem.

Comment: @Lareaper You should at least dynamically allocate memory and copy the string that represents the id into that memory. In this case each id will have its own value - the address of the allocated memory.

Comment: so I could prevent this by dynamically allocating new memory for each new id, correct? Edit: I just realized that I've been thinking of id as an integer this entire time.. Wow do I feel dumb. Time to make some changes to my code!

Comment: @Lareaper "*and I am, to my knowledge, the only person in the class who has had this problem.*"  That is because writing to an uninitialized pointer is undefined behavior.  The program may "work", crash, not crash but give wrong results, work 1,000 times and fail on try 1,001, work on all your friends computers and fail on yours, work on yours only and fails for everyone else, etc.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I should initialize the pointer to NULL then, correct?

Comment: @Lareaper If the actual id is a string then you should either declare the data member id as a character array and copy the string with id there or as I said allocate a memory of an appropriate size and copy the string there.

Comment: @Lareaper  So now you will read into a NULL pointer.  That shouldn't sound right to you.